# How do I concatenate sequential files in order with Java?

Tags: java, file-io, concatenation

I have a directory that contains sequentially numbered log files and some Excel spreadsheets used for analysis. The log file are ALWAYS sequentially numbered beginning at zero, but the number of them can vary. I am trying to concatenate the log files, in the order they were created into a single text file which will be a concatenation of all the log files.

For instance, with log files foo0.log, foo1.log, foo2.log would be output to concatenatedfoo.log by appending foo1 after foo0, and foo2 after foo1.

I need to count all the files in the given directory with the extension of *.log, using the count to drive a for-loop that also generates the file name for concatenation. I'm having a hard time finding a way to count the files using a filter...none of the Java Turtorials on file operations seem to fit the situation, but I'm sure I'm missing something. Does this approach make sense? or is there an easier way?

```
int numDocs = [number of *.log docs in directory];
 //
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfFiles; i++) {
     fileNumber = Integer.toString(i);
     try
     {
          FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("\\\\Path\\to\\file\\foo" + fileNumber + ".log");
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
          try
          {
               BufferedWriter metadataOutputData = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("\\\\Path\\to\\file\\fooconcat.log").append());
               metadataOutputData.close();
          }
           //
          catch (IOException e)  // catch IO exception writing final output
          {
               System.err.println("Exception: ");
               System.out.println("Exception: "+ e.getMessage().getClass().getName());
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     catch (Exception e)    // catch IO exception reading input file
     {
          System.err.println("Exception: ");
          System.out.println("Exception: "+ e.getMessage().getClass().getName());
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: Open a *single* OS. Then, for each IS - open, loop [read IS/write OS] and close in turn. Finally, you can close the OS after everything is written. Even if an OS is opened for appending (as per above), something must *still* be written to it (as not done above).

Comment: Also, instead of counting and then trying to derive the filenames, maybe use a [directory listing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#listdir) if it is suitable to use with the required heuristics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    final int BUFFERSIZE = 1024 << 8;
    File baseDir = new File("C:\\path\\logs\\");

    // Get the simple names of the files ("foo.log" not "/path/logs/foo.log")
    String[] fileNames = baseDir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".log");
        }
    });

    // Sort the names
    Arrays.sort(fileNames);

    // Create the output file
    File output = new File(baseDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar + "MERGED.log");
    try{
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output), BUFFERSIZE);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];
        int bytesRead;
        final byte[] newLine = "\n".getBytes(); // use to separate contents

        for(String s : fileNames){
            // get the full path to read from
            String fullName = baseDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar + s;
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fullName),BUFFERSIZE);
            while((bytesRead = in.read(bytes,0,bytes.length)) != -1){
                out.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            // close input file and ignore any issue with closing it
            try{in.close();}catch(IOException e){}
            out.write(newLine); // seperation
        }

        out.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This code DOES assume that the "sequential naming" would be zero padded such that they will lexigraphically (?? sp) sort correctly.  i.e. The files would be

- 0001.log (or blah0001.log, or 0001blah.log etc)
- 0002.log
- ....
- 0010.log

and not

- 1.log
- 2.log
- ...
- 10.log

The latter pattern will not sort correctly with the code I have given.

Comment: This one works brilliantly just out of the box...except that my filenames are `foo0.log` ... `foo10.log` ... etc. But renaming for sorting or some such should be relatively simple to accomplish.

Comment: If you want to have it sort with your current convention, just replace my line, "`Arrays.sort(fileNames);` with @aetheria 's answer's section of `Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {...}` .  That *should* work, but I did not test.

Answer (score 2):

By having the log folder as a `File` object, you can code like this

```
for (File logFile : logFolder.listFiles()){
    if (logFile.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".log")){
        numDocs++;
    }
}
```

to find the number of log files.

Comment: best answer I found

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code for you.

```
File dir = new File("C:/My Documents/logs");
File outputFile = new File("C:/My Documents/concatenated.log");
```

Find the ".log" files:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".log") && file.isFile();
    }
});
```

Sort them into the appropriate order:

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
        return numberOf(file1).compareTo(numberOf(file2));
    }

    private Integer numberOf(File file) {
        return Integer.parseInt(file.getName().replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
    }
});
```

Concatenate them:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
try {
    for (File file : files) {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            int charCount;
            while ((charCount = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, charCount);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }
} finally {
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: I am having some issues with the concatenation step...I keep getting "catch without try" or "exception must be caught errors"? and I can't seem to add them in the right places. Not ~terribly~ familiar with method `@Override`s so I think my perception of scope for the try/catch pairs is a bit hosed...? I'll be researching that via the Java Tutorials, but in the meantime, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I would;

- open the output file once. Just use a PrintWriter.
- in a loop ...

  - create a File for each possible file
  - if it doesn't exist break the loop.
  - Using a BufferedReader

    - to read the lines of the file with readLine()
    - write each line to the output file.

You should be able to do this with about 12 lines of code. I would pass the IOExceptions to the caller.

Comment: Assuming all the logs come from the same source, and don't need encoding conversion, I'd suggest using byte streams, rather than readers and writers, as the latter are superfluous, and also risk corrupting the contents if you're not careful about the encoding (UTF-8, Cp1252 etc).

Comment: @aetheria This would also preserve original newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SequenceInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html) for concatenation of `FileInputStreams`.
To see all log files [File.listFiles(FileFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) can be used.
It will give you *unsorted* array with files. To sort files in right order, use `Arrays.sort`.
Code example:

```
static File[] logs(String dir) {
    File root = new File(dir);
    return root.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.isFile() && pathname.getName().endsWith(".log");
        }
    });
}

static String cat(final File[] files) throws IOException {
    Enumeration<InputStream> e = new Enumeration<InputStream>() {
        int index;

        @Override
        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return index < files.length;
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream nextElement() {
            index++;
            try {
                return new FileInputStream(files[index - 1]);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("File not available!", ex);
            }
        }
    };
    SequenceInputStream input = new SequenceInputStream(e);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int c;
    while ((c = input.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String dir = "<path-to-dir-with-logs>";
    File[] logs = logs(dir);
    for (File f : logs) {
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(cat(logs));
}
```